# What are Promotional Text and Subtitle in iTunesConnection?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Promotional Text and Subtitle are the new feature in iTuneconnection which is available in iOS 11.0 or above. Subtitle is optional. But Promotional Text is not mentioned as optional. Which text we need to write as Promotional Text. Is it for only current app or any other apps using same developer account?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Promotional Text (or Description)**

it is optional we can update the description on any time.

> Your app’s promotional text appears at the top of the description and is limited to 170 characters. **You can update it at any time without having to submit a new version of your app. Consider using promotional text to share the latest news about your app, which can include new promotions for your app or in-app purchases, upcoming features or content, limited- time sales, or other events within your app**.

for more information you can get appstore [product page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/) and [here also](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/whats-new/)

Comment: How quickly will the update be reflected on the app store?

Comment: @Bn.F76 - valuable question I will check and let u know

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that the Promotional Text can be edited at any time, but, from now on, you are unable to change the App Description without submitting a new version of the app.

Answer (score 3):

**Promotional Text is limited to 170 char and below image described its position.**

---

[image]

---

Credit to below url.

https://medium.com/@kerenberger/app-store-promotional-text-tips-7e7a4388f213

Answer (score 1):

> Promotional Text and Subtitle are the new feature in iTuneconnection
>   which is available in iOS 11.0 or above.

Yes, that's correct.

> Subtitle is optional. But Promotional Text is not mentioned as
>   optional.

For now, as iOS 11 is still yet to be released, it's optional and might stay the same for coming years, unless Apple changes the policy and makes it mandatory (which I doubt would happen).

> Which text we need to write as Promotional Text. Is it for only
>   current app or any other apps using same developer account?

This is based on the app. Different apps for the same developer account can have different promotional text.

[image]